# How to use GROUP BY with this data

Tags: mysql

I got a mysql table called `links`, which has the following columns:

`productId, fromUserId, toUserId, createdTimestamp`

multiple users could link the same product to a user.

What I want is a `GROUP BY` to get all 'links' where `toUserId = <some userId>`.
Since 1 product can be linked multiple times (multiple rows), I want the output to be grouped per `productId`. So to get something looking like:

`productId1, fromUserId1, fromUserId2, fromUserId3, newestCreatedTimestamp`

`productId2, fromUserId1, fromUserId2, newestCreatedTimestamp`

Right now I group these rows at the application level, since I don't understand how to do this in mysql. I'm no mysql expert and the docs are anything but simple (my opinion)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`GROUP_CONCAT` aggregator function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat), to include all `fromUserId` entries into a row. This will generate a comma separated list of all `fromUserId` entries associated with that `GROUP BY`.

```
SELECT `productId`, 
       `toUserId`, 
       GROUP_CONCAT( `fromUserId` ) AS `fromUserIds`
       MAX( `createdTimestamp`) AS `timestamp`
FROM `links`
GROUP BY `productId`, `toUserId`
```

Inserted `MAX()` as per comment below.

Comment: Thanks for the response. How to add only the latest timestamp (its a UNIX timestamp in secs), so the highest `createdTimestamp` value.

Comment: @aremie Edited. Just use another aggregator: `MAX()`.

Comment: Looking at the other answer. Does your's get the wanted result. The other answer is so much longer. Without a JOIN would ofcourse be preferable!

Comment: @aremie Just test both and see, which fits your need ,-)